# Does exactly once processing configuration in a Kafka Stream guarantee only read committed reads?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

There's an excellent series of articles regarding Kafka transactions and exactly once delivery.
[In one of them](https://www.confluent.io/blog/exactly-once-semantics-are-possible-heres-how-apache-kafka-does-it/) the author says about consumers:

> So on the Consumer side, you have two options for reading transactional messages, expressed through the “isolation.level” consumer config:
>
> read_committed: In addition to reading messages that are not part of a transaction, also be able to read ones that are, after the
>   transaction is committed.
>
> read_uncommitted: Read all messages in offset order without waiting for transactions to be committed. This option is similar to
>   the current semantics of a Kafka consumer.

That is to say, normal consumer applications must specify `read_committed` if the only want to read commit writes from the topic.

However regarding Kafka Streams:

> All you need to make your Streams application employ exactly once
>   semantics, is to set this config “processing.guarantee=exactly_once”.
>   This causes all of the processing to happen exactly once; this
>   includes making both the processing and also all of the materialized
>   state created by the processing job that is written back to Kafka,
>   exactly once.

Nothing is explicitly said about the reads in the KStream. When `exactly_once` is configured, does the KStream only read committed messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes KStream will only read committed messages, it's not clearly stated in the documentation but in the [StreamsConfig JavaDoc](https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/StreamsConfig.html) you will find the information:

> If "processing.guarantee" is set to "exactly_once", Kafka Streams does not allow users to overwrite the following properties (Streams setting shown in parentheses):
>   "isolation.level" (read_committed) - Consumers will always read committed data only
>   "enable.idempotence" (true) - Producer will always have idempotency enabled
>   "max.in.flight.requests.per.connection" (5) - Producer will always have one in-flight request per connection